# What are the various joint types available in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Revolute, prismatic, continuous and what else?

Could somebody point me to the right resource to look at to get such information.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7657/what-are-the-various-joint-types-available-in-gazebo?/) by [pmaini](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/600/pmaini/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can find the joint types supported by SDF in the [SDF documentation](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/sdformat/api/1.5.html#joint372):

> The type of joint, which must be one
> of the following: (**revolute**) a hinge
> joint that rotates on a single axis
> with either a fixed or continuous
> range of motion, (**gearbox**) geared
> revolute joints, (**revolute2**) same as
> two revolute joints connected in
> series, (**prismatic**) a sliding joint
> that slides along an axis with a
> limited range specified by upper and
> lower limits, (**ball**) a ball and socket
> joint, (**universal**), like a ball joint,
> but constrains one degree of freedom,
> (**piston**) similar to a Slider joint
> except that rotation around the
> translation axis is possible.

---

Originally posted by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) with karma: 186 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmaini](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/600/pmaini/) on 2014-12-10**:
Thanx. This is the link I need. All new documentation refers the reader to sdformat.org.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-12-12**:
Actually `piston` is not a valid joint type. Here's a list of [ODE joint types](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEPhysics.cc#cl-682).

**Comment by [Sylvain Joyeux](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1168/sylvain-joyeux/) on 2015-04-02**:
I had the same problem than pmaini, the list of valid joint types cannot be found on sdformat.org, which is a pity

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2015-04-02**:
http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=joint has been updated, thanks for pointing that out.

**Comment by [Dennis Leroy Wigand](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2423/dennis-leroy-wigand/) on 2016-01-28**:
Just for the sake of consistency: There is now also a fixed joint: "(fixed) a joint with zero degrees of freedom that rigidly connects two links".

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-11-01**:
Hi there, thank you so much for the valuable question. I was wondering how to add a ball and socket joint in gazebo, I mean what would be the xacro syntax for that, I would really appreciate if you would kindly point out any example.

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2617/abdullah/) on 2016-11-01**:
I could not find a ball joint example or simulate it properly.